# Background processing of Sql Queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am from .NET background and I forwarded my steps for SQL Server. I want to know that how this statement works

```
Select x,y,z FROM tbldemo Where x > something
```

What I understand the sql compiler [if any], compile the right side first [just like .NET] and produce a bit result, i.e. if x > something, then it produce true. After than Select x,y.z will run and than it is filtered with the where clause.

I am asking this question because I want to learn sql in the same way I know .NET. Might be this question sounds weird to you. 
Please let me know how to know how sql is working on these queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fascinating topic (to me at least). This article should help you:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/